# I can't receive the customer object of my stripe checkout session

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

In my frontend I call my checkout session with the prebuild-stripe-payment, after the checkout session is completed as per the guide I try to receive the customer object in order to have the payment details, the payment is successful (lo I see from the stripe dashboard) but in my success page I don't get the object it's like in the example so I can't show the customer name.

This is my code :

```
 app.post("/create-checkout-session", cors(), async (req, res) => {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
          {
            price: "price_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        tax_id_collection: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        phone_number_collection: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        mode: "subscription",
        allow_promotion_codes: true,
        success_url: `${MY_DOMAIN}/order/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${MY_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,
        subscription_data: {
          trial_period_days: 30,
        },
        automatic_tax: { enabled: true },
      });
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    });
    
    
    app.post("/order/success", async (req, res) => {
   
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
      const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);
    
      res.send(`<html><body><h1>Thanks for your order, ${customer.name}!</h1></body></html>`);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirect from Checkout to your success URL is not a POST request, it's a GET request, so your `app.post` route will not work.  If you switch to `app.get` I believe you'll see the behavior you expect.

Comment: I just try with get request but not work

Comment: Can you add logging to your `app.get` success route to confirm it's getting called?  And to see the query variables getting provided?  Then update your question with that detail.

Comment: the problem is that /order/success is never called

Comment: I solved it, in the MY_DOMAIN constant I accidentally entered the frontend port not the backend one so it never made the request because it wasn't called, thanks for the help